# MongoEngine GenericReferenceField Advanced Query

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

Overview:

My User document references an Image document with FileFields. You cannot deepcopy an object with a FileField (why not?). Deep copying a user document  dereferences the associated Image (with FileField) thus fails.

---

I'm trying to query a collection using MongoEngine (0.7.8) and if I query as such:

```
    >>> cls.objects(Q(author=devin_user))
    [<FollowUserEvent: [<User: Devin> => <User: Strike>]>]
    # Querying author works fine

    >>> cls.objects(Q(parent=strike_user))
    [<FollowUserEvent: [<User: Devin> => <User: Strike>]>]
    # Querying parent works fine

    >>> cls.objects(Q(parent=strike_user) & Q(author=devin_user))
    *** TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the '__deepcopy__' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
    # Definitely fails here, but why?


    # Even stranger, if I combine a query on parent and hidden_at it succeeds, but if I combine a query on author and hidden_at it gloriously fails
    >>> cls.objects(Q(parent=strike_user) & Q(hidden_at=None))
    [<FollowUserEvent: [<User: Devin> => <User: Strike>]>]
    # Querying parent works fine

    >>> cls.objects(Q(author=devin_user) & Q(hidden_at=None))
    *** TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the '__deepcopy__' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
    # Boom!
```

strike_user and devin_user are two user documents. Here is what Event looks like (by the way, it does allow inheritance).

```
    class Event(Document):                                             
       """                                                            
       :param anti: tells if an event is related to an inverse event  
           e.g. follow/unfollow, favorite/unfavorite                  
       :param partner: relates an anti-event to an event.             
           only set on the undoing event                              
       """                                                            
       author = GenericReferenceField(required=True)                  
       parent = GenericReferenceField(required=True)                  
       created_at = DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.now)
       hidden_at = DateTimeField()                                    

       anti = BooleanField(default=False)                             
       partner = ReferenceField('Event', dbref=False)                 
       meta = {                                                       
           'cascade': False,                                          
           'allow_inheritance': True }

       def __repr__(self):
           action = "=/>" if self.anti else "=>"
           return "<%s: [%s %s %s]>" % (self.__class__.__name__,
               self.author.__repr__(), action, self.parent.__repr__())
```

Seems like a bug to me, but I'm very interested to hear feedback :)

---

Update:

It seems that mongoengine/queryset.py:98 calls copy.deepcopy. This follows a ReferenceField, and tries to copy it's FileField data, too. Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

```
    Class Image(Document):
        file = FileField(required=True)

    Class User(Document):
        name = StringField()
        image = ReferenceField('Image')

    >>> copy.deepcopy(user)
    *** TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If ...

    >>> user.image = None
    >>> copy.deepcopy(user)
    <User: Devin>
```

Comment: I really do believe this is a bug. I've worked around the problem by defining `author` and `parent` as `ReferenceField`s (dbref=True) on the child classes versus the (now abstract) parent class's `GenericReferenceField`s. //

Now when I query, I must do so on the child class, even though I've left `author` and `parent` as `GenericReferenceField`s on the parent. Strangely, even though I specify dbref=True on the children's `author` and `parent` fields, I cannot query on the parent class: i.e.:

>>> docs.Event.objects(author=docs.Event.objects[0].author) # []

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/mongoengine-users/GenericReferenceField/mongoengine-users/4S3ITUE7K5s/vEuISza3XEwJ a bit more about this, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this is a bug! What I've said in my overview is correct. [Status of the bug

Helpful Links:

[status of the bug](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/198)

[mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoengine-users/4S3ITUE7K5s)